# POST request (form data) with JetBrains HTTP Client doesn't work

Tags: curl, httpclient, opentext

This request to a OpenText Content Server works with the curl, but doesn't work with the JetBrains HTTP Client.

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://myserver/api/v1/auth' \
--form 'username="myuser"' \
--form 'password="mypassword"'
```

This command above works as expected.

```
POST myserver.mydomain
Accept: */*
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=WebAppBoundary

--WebAppBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"

myuser
--WebAppBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

mypassword
--WebAppBoundary--
```

This doesn't work, returns a message about a wrong password.

I would appreciate any suggestions regarding the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should've used "Content-Type: text/plain".
This works just fine.

```
POST http://myserver.local/api/v1/auth
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------974767299852498929531610575

-----------------------------974767299852498929531610575
content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"
Content-Type: text/plain

myusername
-----------------------------974767299852498929531610575
content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"
Content-Type: text/plain

mypassword
-----------------------------974767299852498929531610575--
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type